# Navigation Controller Problem With SceneDelegate

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, swift5

Hello I'm try the hide my navigation controller's back button for all my views. Because that I'm creating my navigation controller in sceneDelegate it work normal but just back button I can't hide it. I have been try all possibilities I can't fix it. (Also I try to change back button title I didn't change as well)

```
func scene(_ scene: UIScene, willConnectTo session: UISceneSession, options connectionOptions: UIScene.ConnectionOptions) {

        guard let newScene = (scene as? UIWindowScene) else { return }
        window = UIWindow(windowScene: newScene)

        let navigationController = UINavigationController()

        navigationController.navigationBar.backItem?.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Test"
        navigationController.navigationBar.backItem?.hidesBackButton = true
        navigationController.navigationItem.hidesBackButton = true
        navigationController.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.accessibilityElementsHidden = true

        let appStartPoint = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("CityController", owner: self, options: nil)?.first as! CityController
        navigationController.setViewControllers([appStartPoint], animated: true)
                window?.rootViewController = navigationController
        window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
```

Comment: Can you show the xib CityController as the appStartPoint is first view controller, there is no point hiding back button. It should not be present there at first instance.

Comment: Actually i have 4 xib I know in first there is no point hiding but I want to hide back button in my second third and fourth screens

Comment: You must have implemented the back button functionality or are you using back buttons from navigation controller

Comment: I'm using back button from navigation controller

Comment: So you need to override the button functionality for your second and fourth screens.If you are hiding them just hide them in the view controllers where you present these xibs that should do

Comment: Thank you for your help